# Why are all the options to select files in the commit dialog grayed out for TortoiseSVN using Windows 10?

Tags: tortoisesvn, windows-10

I recently rebuilt my development machine upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 10 and reinstalling the latest release version of TortoiseSVN.

Whenever I try to do a commit, several of the options are grayed out:

[image: Screenshot]
(Highlighting added for emphasis)

These were working when I was in Windows 7, but none of my settings migrated when I upgraded to Windows 10.  Is there a configuration setting to enable these options?